# Export/import only part of Tags/Triggers/Variables in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'd like to re-use some of Tags, Triggers and Variables from one container in another one. Standard import/export doesn't fit my needs, because it simply exports and imports everything without a possibility to select, what I want to transfer.

The only way I see now - export everything, and then cleanup the resulting JSON-file from non-needed elements, but it still looks hacky and bad practice.

Are there any better ways to do partial export or import?

Comment: Simo Ahava has written a nice tools that allow to copy assets from one account to another: http://www.gtmtools.com/. If that does not fit your needs you can roll your own tools via the API: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/.

Comment: Simo Ahava tool is pretty neat, but I cannot see any options to pick and choose the element one wants to export

Comment: Here is some third party tool can help you to do this please read this blog link https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/copy-google-tag-manager-tags/#gref